# Does Android 4.x versions support password protection for android application from uninstalling?

Tags: android

I am beginner in android. So i would like to know about the password protection for android application in 4.x versions from uninstalling. I have implemented it in 2.3 but it doesnt work in higher versions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its just only common info. I wanna know whether it supports in 4.x versions or not

Answer (score 3):

No version of Android supports password protection for uninstallation of apps.

A few apps have managed to find workarounds by monitoring logcat etc, but Google actively fixes these and they rarely work in newer versions of Android.

At best, you can ask the user to make your app a Device Admin, which will prevent uninstallation until the app is removed from the Device Admin status.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you explain how to make it Device Admin one